# Power BI develop query with cached dataset

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

When developing a query in Power BI with a database data source, making any changes causes the query editor to 'start from scratch' and re-query the database.

Wondering if there is a workaround that allows you to develop a query without repeated long wait times by eg downloading a temporary local flat file of the full dataset which can be used to develop the query offline and can then be swapped out for the live database connection when you are happy with it.

Importing the data once, exporting as a csv from a Power BI table visualisation and re-importing as a new data source would work but maybe there's a simpler way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two approaches you can use.

1. If your database supports query folding, make the first step take just the top 200 records whilst you develop your query. Once your happy with it, remove the firstN filter.
2. Load the entire table to the model, export it to a csv using DAX studio, develop your query using the CSV and then switch back to the DB once you're happy with it.

Comment: Thanks for this. Hadn't thought of DAX studio, much easier than exporting from a Power BI visual! Seems surprising that Power BI doesn't have a 'freeze snapshot' option baked in - could even have a row limit you could set.